# Spring MVC Web Application - proper use of Model

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am developing Web Application in Java using Spring Framework. On one page, I am letting user pick year. Here is the code:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/pick_year", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String pickYear(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("yearModel", new YearModel);
        return "pick_year";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/open_close_month_list", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processYear(Model model, @ModelAttribute("yearModel") YearModel yearModel) {
        int year = yearModel.getYear();
        // Processing
    }
}


public class YearModel { 
    private int year;

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
}
```

This implementation works, but I would like to use something simplier to get year from the user. I think making special model just to get one integer is not very good approach.

So, my question is: Is it possible to somehow simplify this code?

Thank you for any help.
Milan

Comment: that code doesn't compile. Are you sure it's the real code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you use the model to pass data from controller to view, and you use `@RequestParam` to get data from a submitted form in a controller. Meaning, your POST method would look like:

```
public String processYear(@RequestParam("year") int year) {
    // Processing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you just need to store the integer, you don't need to create a whole new special class to hold it

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/pick_year", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String pickYear(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("year", 2012);
        return "pick_year";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/open_close_month_list", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processYear(@ModelAttribute("year") int year) {
        // Processing
    }
}
```

What you could instead (if possible) is rework your view so that you can use `@RequestParam` to pass directly an integer to your method `pickYear` rendering it into the view so that this parameter could be passed onto the second method `processYear` in the same way.

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    // In the pick_year view hold the model.year in any hidden form so that
    // it can get passed to the process year method
    @RequestMapping(value = "/pick_year", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView pickYear(@RequestParam("year") int year) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("pick_year");
        model.addAttribute("year", 2012);
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/open_close_month_list", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processYear(@RequestParam("year") int year) {
        // Processing
    }
}
```